# MyFaces: exceeding maximum Paramaters allowed per request

Tags: jsf, primefaces, request, websphere, myfaces

The application I'm involved in was deployed to test server (WebSphere 7) from where we're getting errors we've never seen before:

This is the message about exceeding maximum number of parameters allowed per request, additionally written with error:

```
28.01.2013 15:51:38 SEVERE exceeding maximum Paramaters allowed per request -> 1000 ,current parameterSize-> 1000 cannot add more. 
28.01.2013 15:51:38 SEVERE An exception occurred 
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:191)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
```

I've never seen a parameter for configuring maximul parameters count, neither have I found it in http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html. So, what is this `parameterSize` param, where can I configure it?

The application is embedded as **EAR**, is using **MyFaces 2.0.7** and **PrimeFaces 3.4**.

Comment: I guess the solution won't be allowing to send more parameters, instead **reduce** the number of parameters you send to the request.

Comment: It's hardly possible when using PrimeFaces, for example pick list is putting every item as parameter, probably this is the responsible for so much of them

Comment: You could change the `process` attribute of `<p:commandButton />` or `<p:ajax>` or the component you're using to send the request.

Comment: @Luiggi: that's a server side thing. You probably meant `partialSubmit` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC yes that's what I meant.

Comment: lech: this is not a MyFaces thing. This is a WebSphere thing. So look in documentation of WebSphere instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `BalusC` for quick response, through the exception comes from MyFaces class, it is the WebSphere setting

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest 

You can use this property to change the maximum number of parameters allowed in your inbound requests, based on your applications and environment. The maximum number of parameters allowed per inbound request (GET or POST) defaults to 10000.
```

source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592923

Comment: MyFaces didn't throw. It delegated. For starters, you should look at the root cause of the stacktrace (the bottommost part) to learn about the root cause of the exception.